# Count for Member Posts in Ghost 3.x

Tags: ghost-blog

Does anyone know how to get a total count for the number of posts that are for members.paid only in Ghost 3.x?

So far I have the following. But I cant seem to find the correct filter to only show the members.paid articles.

```
{{#get "posts" limit="all" }}
    {{posts.length}}
{{/get}}
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution posted over on the Ghost forum:
https://forum.ghost.org/t/get-total-count-of-member-paid-posts/12117

```
{{#get "posts" limit="all" filter="visibility:paid"}}
    {{posts.length}}
{{/get}}
```